# В этом предложении составное именное сказуемое или простое?

Tags: синтаксис

"Папа всегда очень хорошо относится к бабушке".

Comment: Папа относится к бабушке - не звучит. Папа хорошо относится к бабушке. Хорошо относится - сказуемое. Всегда очень - предикация какая-то дополнительная, которую так же можно включить в состав сказуемого, то есть сказуемое это "всегда очень хорошо относится", а можно не включать, сказав, что всегда очень относится к хорошо. Вообще относится такой себе глагол. Фраза звучит: Папа к бабушке хорошо. Сказуемое *хорошо*. Ответ на: Как папа относится к бабушке? Бабушке - дополнение.

Comment: То есть по большому счёту сказуемое *хорошо*, всегда очень - обстоятельства действия, относится - тоже какое-то обстоятельство.  Можно задать вопрос, это как например: Идет шагает по лесу. Сказуемое идет или шагает? Или шагает - обстоятельство?

Answer (score 5):

Сказуемое - это то, что говорится о подлежащем. Основную информацию о подлежащем в данном случае выражает глагол "относится", поэтому это **ПГС**. ДЛЯ **СИС** характерно наличие глагола-связки. Глагол **"относиться"** ни в коем случае нельзя считать глаголом-связкой, потому что он обладает полнотой значения:

> 1. К кому-чему. Составить своё представление о ком-, чём-л.; повести себя, встретить, принять что-л. каким-л. образом. О. к подросткам с
>    пониманием. О. к кому-л. как к своему недругу. Недоверчиво отнёсся к
>    новому знакомству. Не знаю, как о. к митинговым призывам.
>    Доброжелательно о. к заявлению депутата.

---

Кроме того, к наречию "хорошо" задается логичный вопрос - как? Его нельзя игнорировать, т.к. фразеологизации выражения в данном случае не наблюдается.

---

В качестве проверки можно взять другой глагол с похожим смыслом и сравнить его с глаголами-связками:

-Папа всегда очень хорошо **был** о бабушке (связка)!

-Папа всегда очень хорошо **отзывался** о бабушке (полноценный глагол)!

Comment: Есть еще синтаксически неделимые (несвободные) сочетания. Синтаксическая неделимость словосочетаний объясняется семантической недостаточностью их ГЛАВНОГО СЛОВА. Семантически недостаточное слово в таком сочетании не может употребляться самостоятельно, а используется только только как как КОМПОНЕНТ словосочетания. Можно ли считать "хорошо относиться" таким сочетанием или нельзя? Какая здесь разница? Было сказано: "Папа относится к бабушке - не звучит". Как эта проблема решается, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Тут еще проблема, что относился то папа, но **к** бабушке. То есть папа - это не субъект действия, а скорее объект воздействия отношений. Бабушка для папы всегда очень хороша - как-то так, относился, это какой-то глагол, который разворачивает субъект-объектную предикацию наоборот. У связки есть еще направление.

Comment: @Sharon Не нужно пытаться убирать слово из контекста. Понятно, что глагол несамостоятелен, однако  значение у него четко определенное, не связочное. К тому же это "хорошо" заменяется на другие наречия. Рассматривать данное словосочетание как одно целое я не вижу смысла, потому что грамматические связи между словами четко устанавливаются: относился (как) хорошо. "Относиться хорошо", - это очень абстрактная формулировка, это не то же самое, что "иметь намерение". Еще раз напомню, что данный глагол способен сам выразить полноту смысла, пусть и не может употребляться сам.

Comment: Не глагол не самостоятелен, папа не самостоятелен. Тут единственное значимое слово - "хорошо". Как папа относится к бабушке? - Хорошо. И относится - это термин из математики, отношение, пропорция - это оно, потому он и не выражает ничего, служебный глагол.

Comment: А в чем тут дело?  Ведь некоторые распространители можно убирать из предложения, а некоторые вот нет. Разница какая между ними какая. Например: Мне не нравится его взгляд. Здесь "его взгляд"  неразложимое сочетание (дополнение). Или еще вариант: оказать помощь (единое сочетание). Он хороший человек. Сказуемое "хороший человек".

Comment: @Sharon Вы смешали все в одну кучу. То, что "хорошо" нельзя убрать из данного контекста, говорит лишь о том, что глагол не употребляется самостоятельно, однако для определения подлежащего ему не нужны обязательные распространители. "Хорошо" более точно описывает картину отношений, но основная информация сосредоточена в глаголе (отец относится). Как относится, почему, в какой момент времени - для определения сказуемого этого не важно, поскольку смысловой спаянности компонентов здесь нет.

Comment: Он хороший человек - человек тоже термин. Мне кажется, вы путаете термины и глаголы-действия. Глаголы - это слова обозначающие действия. Папа несет хорошее к бабушке. несет - глагол. Папа хороший человек - человек - термин. Папа хорошо "относится" к бабушке - относится - термин. Термины это слова специфические, я бы их не относил ни к подлежащим ни к сказуемым, это обстоятельства или дополнения, но не полноценные слова. Термины - это абстракции. Икс делить на игрек - делить это глагол? нет, это просто добавка к предикату, причем в связки с предлогом. Икс делить игрек сказать нельзя.

Comment: Можно сказать: Икс на игрек. Но нельзя сказать: икс делить игрек. Получается предлог важнее глагола?

Comment: Дело не в том, что "делить" слово неправильное. А в том что тут, делить - это не глагол. Это как местоимение которое становится частицей при определенных обстоятельствах. То есть одно и тоже слово по форме, может быть другой частью речи. Вот тут этот "глагол" не несет никакого значения, значения несет предлог, наречие или еще какое слово. А "вроде как глагол" - это слово без которого можно и обойтись. Поэтому я бы назвал такие слова -дополнения или обстоятельства, терминами или еще как-нибудь, потому что это терминологические дополнения, а не существительные или глаголы.

Answer (score 2):

Это одна **из самых сложных тем** в грамматическом анализе, в том числе для школьников. Вот обычный **разбор** предложения: Папа (что делает?) — относится, но это звучит как-то странно.

2. В принятом ответе говорится о **составном именном сказуемом**, но не эта тема должна быть в центре внимания. Здесь сказуемое надо сравнивать **с устойчивыми сочетаниями** (глагольными фразеологизмами), например: Оказать помощь — помочь. Это п**ростое глагольное сказуемое (ПГС).** Но ведь можно разбирать и так: Им оказали помощь. Что (сделали?) оказали, где помощь — дополнение. Так как же правильно? И это **школьный** вопрос.
3. Другой похожий вариант — **синтаксически неделимые** (несвободные) сочетания. Синтаксическая неделимость словосочетаний объясняется семантической **недостаточностью** их ГЛАВНОГО СЛОВА. Семантически недостаточное слово в таком сочетании не может употребляться **самостоятельно**, а используется только только как как КОМПОНЕНТ словосочетания. Тоже очень похоже, и тогда все сочетание — это **единый член предложения.**
4. **Так почему** "относиться хорошо" — это не  фразеологизм и не синтаксически неделимое слово? Вот такой **анализ желателен**, а что это не составное именное сказуемое, что нет там связки — это и так понятно.
5. Можно еще рассмотреть **ряд сказуемых**: Папа хорошо относится к бабушке, любит ее, уважает ее. **По семантике** я не вижу разницы между глаголами и глагольным словосочетанием, да и **по грамматике** это **однородный** ряд.
6. И еще любопытно рассмотреть предложение: ***У них хорошие отношения***. Здесь тоже нет неделимого словосочетания? Будем говорить: у них отношения, отношения (какие?).

Comment: Все равно бы не сказал, что "относится хорошо" является синтаксически неделимым сочетанием: у них тогда должна быть одна роль, а тут роли у компонентов совершенно разные (кроме того, речь об обстоятельстве, которое должно включиться в состав, а не о дополнении). Не станете же вы отрицать, что вопрос от глагола более чем уместен? Что касается фразы "оказать помощь", то здесь все куда проще:  "оказать" - это действительно глагол с ослабленным лексическим значением, и это чувствуется на языковом уровне, об "относиться" я такого сказать не могу: у него явно есть свое, полноценное значение.

Comment: Вы считаете, все так считают — значит, это правильно? Довод, конечно, но НЕ  ДОКАЗАТЕЛЬСТВО.  Поэтому я НИЧЕГО не считаю,  это для меня очень сложная тема, В ней много условностей и "коллективной договоренности": подумали и решили так считать.  И о ПОЛНОЦЕННОСТИ глаголов. Специально посмотрела в словаре "оказать и относиться",  но существенной разницы не заметила. Может, вы ее чувствуете на языковом уровне? Но чувства  — это тоже не доказательства, надо что-нибудь более существенное.  (И в ответ я добавила информацию об однородных сказуемых.)

Comment: "У них отношения", - вполне допустимая фраза. А отношения какие: хорошие, скверные, необычные и т.д. - это уже детали. К слову, я не могу принять "хорошего человека" как сказуемое никак, пусть даже так написано в учебнике. Только при инверсии

Comment: "У них отношения"– сейчас так лучше не говорить)  Мне тоже "хороший человек" не нравится, особенно в наше "фантастическое" время. Например: Я человек, а не компьютерная программа и не персонаж из нейросети. Еще мне не нравится связка "состоит из". Я  против  таких мнений пыталась протестовать (с одиночным плакатом), но меня "задвинули", так что пришлось пока смириться.   Для себя"хорошего человека" считаю контекстуально неразложимым сочетанием, а "состоит из" – "третьесортной" связкой (в сец. литературе прочитала, есть такие).

Comment: Кстати, вот что не сказал о неразложимых сочетаниях. Сказать "мужчина [высокого] роста" мы не можем, проговорить женщина [с голубыми] глазами мы тоже не имеем права (если речь не о некрофилке), потому что в такой фразе не будет смысла, однако я могу быть как просто человеком, так  и хорошим человеком, а кроме того, могу еще и назваться человеком хорошим.

Comment: Это да, но дело в том, что неразложимые сочетания бывают разными. Если там грамматическая связь, то сомнений нет.  Я разбирала эту тему, но конца понимания все-таки нет.  Можно посмотреть (при желании) https://proza.ru/2022/10/26/609

Comment: Не знаю, почему вы именно так разобрали это предложение. Для меня во фразе "Его раздражал холодный взгляд Сперанского" слово "Сперанского " было бы несогласованным определением, спаянности компонентов в таком примере не вижу. "Взгляд раздражает", - основа передает суть. Слово "взгляд", как мне кажется, не может ослабеть в значении настолько, чтобы потерять возможность самостоятельно выражать нужный смысл. По крайней мере в школе "Сперанского" бы не включили в состав сказуемого.

Comment: "Пе­ре­жи­ва­ешь тре­вож­ное на­стро­е­ние, ко­то­рое будит во­об­ра­же­ние".Где-то увидела такое предложение. В ответе к заданию было написано ,что "будит воображение"-это составное именное сказуемое ,но глагол "будит" сохранил же свое лексическое значение .Или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: @Анна Это дискуссионный вопрос. Это предложение из открытого банка заданий ОГЭ. В школе ОГИО , к сожалению или счастью, иногда включают в задание. Чтобы проверить себя, нужно заменять оборот глаголом с синонимичным значением. Где-то это сделать легче, как, например, в этом примере: оказать помощь — помочь, одержать победу — победить, а где-то сложнее, однако возможно все равно : будит воображение — возбуждает.

Comment: Спасибо .Странно ,что дискуссионные вопросы включают в экзамен и требуют однозначного ответа .

Comment: Дискуссия: https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=12675 Тема у Кустовой, стр. 6  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf  Вот предложение: Он иногда смотрел в мою сторону, и меня раздражал взгляд. Нормально написано? Думаю, "взгляд"  входит в состав контекстуально неделимых сочетаний.